# Make 8 out of 12 items visible in the viewport with 4 in overflow

Tags: jquery, math

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    ... etc
</div>
```

What im looking to have is a variable where I define how many items that should be visible within the viewport *(= 100% width of the screen)*, example: `containerOneVisibleViewportItems = 10;`.

Assuming I have 12 `<div class="item">` items *(which would leave two items in the overflow)*, this would require setting the `.container1` to `width: 120%` and each `<div class="item">` with `width: 10%`.

So far so good. **My issue is how the math would look if I want to have 8 out of 12 items visible in the viewport** *(which would leave 4 items in the overflow)*. *(all items needs to stay in one line, like a continuous belt)*

I've tried with the following, which ends up wrong:

```
/* container 2 */
var containerTwo = $(".container2");
var containerTwoItem = $(".container2 .item");
var containerTwoLength = containerOneItem.length;
/* container 2 - settings */
var containerTwoVisibleViewportItems = 8;
var containerTwoWidth = containerTwoVisibleViewportItems*containerTwoLength;
var containerTwoItemWidth = (containerTwoVisibleViewportItems*100) / containerOneWidth;

/* container 2 - append */
containerTwo.css("width", containerOneWidth+"%");

containerTwoItem.each(function(index){    
    $(this).css("width",containerTwoItemWidth+"%");
})
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/yptynwv7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First solution ( with fixed height ):

If you divide 100% by itemsCount, you'll get width of one item. Set **overflow: hidden;** and you are good to go. BUT, note that this will only work with fixed height of item that has to be same as the height of the container.

CSS:

```
#container1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
}
```

JS ( jQuery ):

```
var container1        = $( '#container1' );
var items             = $( '.item', container1 );
var itemsInContainer1 = 8;

items.width( ( 100 / itemsInContainer1 ) + '%' );
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ppcwvmm9/

## Second solution ( without fixed height )

You just hide any overflowing element programmatically.

```
var container1        = $( '#container1' );
var items             = $( '.item', container1 );
var itemsInContainer1 = 8;

items.width( ( 100 / itemsInContainer1 ) + '%' );

items.each( function( index, element )
{
    if ( index >= itemsInContainer1 )
    {
        $( element ).hide();
    }
});
```

Code is basically the same, but now, you can remove the `height` property.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/tsekffh2/

## Third solution

In case you want to show all elements, even those which are 'overflowing', you have to extend the width of the container. First, you divide actual `#container1`'s width ( assuming it's 100% wide ) by the number of 'visible items' and you get the width of one item. Then just multiply this number by the count of items in container.

```
var container1        = $( '#container1' );
var items             = $( '.item', container1 );
var itemsInContainer1 = 8;
var itemWidth         = container1.width() / itemsInContainer1;

items.width( itemWidth );

container1.width( itemWidth * items.size() );
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vus6bbw6/

## Forth solution ( based on percentage )

This solution uses percents instead of pixels for purpose of responsivity.

You have to set each item's width to 100% / visibleItemsCount. Each item has have `position:absolute;`. The last step is to programmatically set it's `left` attribute to `itemWidth * countOfItemsOnLeft`

CSS:

```
#container1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}

.item {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

JS:

```
var container1        = $( '#container1' );
var items             = $( '.item', container1 );
var itemsInContainer1 = 8;
var itemWidth         = container1.width() / itemsInContainer1;

items.css( 'width', 100 / itemsInContainer1 + '%' );

items.each( function( index, element )
{
    var percentage = 100 / itemsInContainer1;
    
    $( element ).css( 'left', index * percentage + '%' );   
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/6byd5ryt/

Comment: Hey Jergus! Thanks for contributing - will just check out your examples! I see one issue - I would need the overflow items to keep visibility and keep on floating left without breaking down on a new line - I think for this to be possible, it would be needed to adjust the width of the container based on total number of items

Comment: Just to elaborate - *I would need to keep all floating items on one line (even the overflow items), as were they one long belt - that's what makes this a challenge - atleast for me :)

Comment: I've added third solution :)

Comment: Jergus! Perfect :) I added a wrapper here and its good: http://jsfiddle.net/1tqz8n0m/ - The problem is just it's pixels now, whereas I need it to be defined/calculated with percentage - is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you are able to do it with percents, using the absolute positioning, but that is not the prettiest way to do it. Do you really need it to be calculated by percentage? If yes, why?

Comment: For the purpose of having it responsive. With pixels I need to re-adjust re-calculate everytime browser is re-sized. Why would it need to be position absolute? Isn't it a matter of defining correct percentage width for the main container and items (the same approach as with pixels, but just with percentage)?

Comment: You're amazing - thanks for the variaty of examples, it all makes sence now and with your latest percentage example, it's perfect! Thanks so much for taking the time to elaborate on it all!